# php script for contact form

Tags: php, html, forms

This is the script and form.  When I test it, it immediately validates before someone can even complete the form.  I'm sure it's one easy thing, because this script has worked on other sites I've done. any ideas?

```
<form id="contact" form method="post" action="index.html">

<div class="row half">
<?php  //form validation and email sending will go here

//check to see if the form has been completely filled out or not
$completed = false;

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
     $name = $_POST['name'];
} else {
      $name = NULL;
      echo '<p class="error">You forgot to enter your name!</p>';
}
      if (preg_match ('/^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/', $_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
} else {
      $email = NULL;
      echo '<p class="error">Please enter a valid email address.</p>';
}

     if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {
      $comments = $_POST['message'];
} else {
      $comments = NULL;
      echo '<p class="error">Please include your comments.</p>';
}

 //form has been completed, send email 
 if ($name && $email && $comments) {

 //form has been completed, set to true
 $completed = true;

 $to = "companion@hotmail.com";
 $subject = "Contact Form Submission";
 $message = "Thank you for visiting The Companion!";
 "Name: " . $name . "\r\n".
 "Email: " . $email . "\r\n".
 "Comments: " . $comments . "\r\n";
 $headers = "From: companion@hotmail.com \r\n";
 $headers .= "Cc: ". $email. "\r\n";
 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

 echo '<p class="confirmation">Thank you for contacting us.</br>
 We received your message and will get back to you shortly.</p>';
 } else {  
      //displays if the user has not completely filled out form
      echo '<p class="error">The form has not been filled out completely, please check and try again.</p>';
 } //end if ($name && $email && $comments)

 }//end (isset($_POST['submitted'])
?>

<div class="6u">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) echo $_POST['name']; ?>"/></div>

<div class="6u">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>"/></div>
</div>

<div class="row half">
<div class="12u">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6"><?php if (isset($_POST['comments'])) echo $_POST['comments']; ?></textarea></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="12u"><ul class="actions">
<li><input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Send Message" /></li>
</ul>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
<?php
} //end if ($completed == false)
?>
```

Comment: Change `form method="post"` to `method="post"` - You've already opened it with `<form` - That alone will break your form.

Comment: Plus, you also don't have a form element called/name `submitted` and your entire code is dependant on it (`it`=conditional statement). You may have meant to use `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` based on your `<input type="submit" name="submit"`

Comment: Another thing I spotted `action="index.html"` that won't work unless you've instructed Apache to treat `.html` as PHP. So, you'd need to change it to `action="index.php"` if your handler is called `index.php`

Comment: @Fred-ii-, That wouldn't make a difference since there is a space between "form" and "method". The "form" will be considered it's own attribute and "method" would work as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line in your code from
**if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){**.....................}  to **if (isset($_POST['submit'])){**..............} .
This is because you are using name="submit" in form submit. and trying to check loop with $_POST['submitted'] .

So your code now look like...

index.php.

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="index.php">

<div class="row half">
<?php  //form validation and email sending will go here

//check to see if the form has been completely filled out or not
$completed = false;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
     $name = $_POST['name'];
} else {
      $name = NULL;
      echo '<p class="error">You forgot to enter your name!</p>';
}
      if (preg_match ('/^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/', $_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
} else {
      $email = NULL;
      echo '<p class="error">Please enter a valid email address.</p>';
}

     if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {
      $comments = $_POST['message'];
} else {
      $comments = NULL;
      echo '<p class="error">Please include your comments.</p>';
}

 //form has been completed, send email 
 if ($name && $email && $comments) {

 //form has been completed, set to true
 $completed = true;

 $to = "champanion@hotmail.com";
 $subject = "Contact Form Submission";
 $message = "Thank you for visiting The Champanion!";
 "Name: " . $name . "\r\n".
 "Email: " . $email . "\r\n".
 "Comments: " . $comments . "\r\n";
 $headers = "From: champanion@hotmail.com \r\n";
 $headers .= "Cc: ". $email. "\r\n";
 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

 echo '<p class="confirmation">Thank you for contacting us.</br>
 We received your message and will get back to you shortly.</p>';
 } else {  
      //displays if the user has not completely filled out form
      echo '<p class="error">The form has not been filled out completely, please check and try again.</p>';
 } //end if ($name && $email && $comments)

 }//end (isset($_POST['submit'])
?>

<div class="6u">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) echo $_POST['name']; ?>"/></div>

<div class="6u">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>"/></div>
</div>

<div class="row half">
<div class="12u">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6"><?php if (isset($_POST['comments'])) echo $_POST['comments']; ?></textarea></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="12u"><ul class="actions">
<li><input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Send Message" /></li>
</ul>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
<?php
 //end if ($completed == false)
?>
```

Comment: I made your suggested change of "submit", but I still get the php code showing in the form section - validating before the form is filled out.

Comment: hello @LStrange you need to copy the above code i added as answer and please save it as index.php and run in loacalhost it must works..have furthur issue please comment it.. i think you save file as .html change it to .php and run this. that may me your problem..

Comment: Have you tried with above code in your file index.php on live server or localhost. This should working in my system.if u any have any further issue please comment it here ..i think you save file as .html.  change it to .php and run this. that may be your problem..

Comment: Hello @LStrange why did u not verify this as a genuine answer for your question.do you get your solution in any other way or this have still any problem??

Answer (score 0):

It appears maybe there has been a mix up in the code.

So you want to validate AFTER the form is completed? Change your first if statement to

```
if (isset($_POST['completed'])) {
```

Try removing this as it will always set the value when the script runs, which will cause it to run every time. Leaving it null will prevent it from running until the variable is set.

```
$completed = false;
```

Add this to your form section. It will set a value to the completed with will run the validation script.

```
<input type="hidden" name="completed" value="yes" />
```

These actions should cause your validation script to run WHEN the form is completed. It probably won't solidify your validation script as there are probably some other things that need to be streamlined, but this should resolve the problem you are experiencing currently.

Comment: he should be validating each field individually, then putting the filled items (except passwords) back on the page filled out, then if anything is left empty re display the form partially filled out.  Also don't open a lot of php tags, because it makes things slower, either do a '. $var.', or echo "____ $var ____"

Comment: I agree. I was just addressing the main issue. The validation process could use some streamlining. I kept looking at it and I see that the "completed" variable was set, but wasn't used anywhere in the php. Same goes for submitted, the variable was used in the if statement, but never set anywhere.

Comment: also he should do the short hand for variable loading, whatever that is.

Comment: I changed to 'completed', removed $completed = false; and added <form id="contact" method="post" action="index.html"><input type="hidden" name="completed" value="yes" />.  No change.  Still shows code.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't work on a .html file.

Change action="index.html" to action="index.php"
change the index.html file name to "index.php"

Shall work.

Answer (score -1):

This is much easier to read than what you have.

```
        <div class="6u">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="'.$name.'/></div>
        <div class="6u">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="'.$mail.'"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row half">
        <div class="12u">
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6">'.$comments.'</textarea></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="12u"><ul class="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Send Message" /></li>
        </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
        </form>';
        } //end if ($completed == false)
```

If you used single quotes inside the echo you wouldn't need to do a '.escaped from echo.'

Comment: That wouldn't make a difference since there is a space between "form" and "method". The "form" will be considered it's own attribute and "method" would work as normal.

Comment: Inside of HTML5 custom attributes are allowed by the spec. Now, I agree with you that the `form` attribute shouldn't be there, but the browser will still be able to process the form properly if the document is HTML4.

Comment: I made this change, as well as changing the "if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {" as mentioned by Ajesh VC above.  No luck.  Still showing php in form.